# OS X tools for testing & visualizing network performance between two points

Tags: networking, mac-osx, performance

A client of mine has had intermittent network issues between their office and their server hosted on AWS.

A speedtest (at speedtest.net) shows their bandwidth is fine.

When I test their server, from a different location, the speed is fine – works on my machine.

Can you recommend any tools for OS X which will allow them to visualize connection performance between their location and the host?

Ease of use is important – they are not command line savvy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your relationship with this client and the setup, I'd be tempted to get a small headless workstation with SSH access and connect it to their network with remote access for you. You can script connection tests and such from that system. Something small and out of the way, rather than relying on them to use their own systems and run a procedure that they probably don't want to know about or understand to get results they won't know what to do with.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for some magic.  But this is a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: There could probably be something rigged up, but from the client-interface side, and trying to communicate with you what is happening, you're better off handling it yourself and keeping the burden on you rather than shifting the burden on them. At least in my experience.